# Changing course in Java properties

Tags: java, properties

i use in the project of jar file Atlasclient.jar . the jar file use of properties file.These properties are located in the path src/log4j.properties.
I want to put this file in a different direction.
but,the following error message shows:

```
    log4j_filename = null
DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_FILE = log4j.properties
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (avanegar.SendPayments.SendPaymentThread).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
```

How can I move the file to the.

Comment: is log4j.properties part of your jar file?

Answer (score 0):

Log4j is looking for a configuration file in the root of your classpath on runtime. You can either configure Log4j via property file (`log4j.properties`) or via xml file (`log4j.xml`).

If you are using maven your configuration goes to `src/main/resources`, if you are using ant it's up to you where to put it.

If you have one single jar file as deployable, your configuration file must be located at the root of the jar file.

Please note that sometimes the log4j file is located at `/META-INF/`. In this case log4j if configured programmatically in the `main` method.